# JSF get JSR-303 ValidatorFactory from from FacesContext

Tags: jsf, bean-validation

Is there a way to get the ValidatorFactory from the current faces context?

**Use cases:**

- class-level validation which is not triggered by JSF
- objects created and validated within action method that are not binded to `UIComponent`'s

Comment: If you happen to use OmniFaces (I know you are), you might want to borrow `Platform#getBeanValidatorFactory()`.

Comment: Oh did not knew about it. Why is it not in `Faces` or `FacesLocale` since it depends on current context? I searched there before asking this question.

Comment: To avoid required dependency on bean validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bean validator is usually loaded by some implementation of jsr-299 [CDI - (open web beans etc)...] if its available in CDI you can usually use the faces EL-Resolver to pull it.

For use case 1 and 2:

since it be available in CDI you can simply inject it.

```
public class MyService{
    @Inject
    private ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;
}
```

I would probably go a step further and make this MyService a singleton and use it throughout your service and web layers.

Answer (score 0):

Checking source of [BeanValidator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/BeanValidator.html) the ValidatorFactory can be obtained using:

```
/**
 * Retrieves the ValidatorFactory from the given context
 * 
 * @param context FacesContext
 * 
 * @return {@link ValidatorFactory}
 */
public static ValidatorFactory getValidatorFactory(final FacesContext context)
{
    final Object cachedObject = context.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap()
        .get(BeanValidator.VALIDATOR_FACTORY_KEY);

    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;

    if (cachedObject instanceof ValidatorFactory)
        validatorFactory = (ValidatorFactory) cachedObject;
    else
        try
        {
            validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
            context.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap()
                .put(BeanValidator.VALIDATOR_FACTORY_KEY, validatorFactory);
        }
        catch (final ValidationException e)
        {
            throw new FacesException("Could not build a default Bean Validator factory", e);
        }

    return validatorFactory;
}
```